# Links on user page are assembled to the wrong destination

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, hyperlinks, javascript

I'll admit that I don't know how your pages are constructed, and it might not even be possible to fix this problem.  However, recently we had an [issue](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1434/user-pages-linking-to-the-api/) where a user was unable to use his userpage because [his javascript failed to load properly](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1434/user-pages-linking-to-the-api/1444#1444).

Now, I can understand that in the case of failure on the user's end it is not longer the responsibility of SO to guarantee user experience; however if we look at the cause for poor user experience (in this case) it was because the buttons for question sorting link to the api instead of the page.

These buttons' "click" behavior is overridden to produce the correct ajax call, but in the case of javascript failing to load, or the user right-clicking and selecting `open in new tab`, the user is redirected to the api directly instead of back to the same page with different sorting.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open up [any user page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137041/tzenes)
2. Select the `stats` tab
3. Right click on `recent` and select `open in new tab`
4. Notice how the user is directed to: `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/api/userquestions.html?userid=137041&page=1&pagesize=10&sort=recent`

Expected Behavior: the user should be directed to `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137041/tzenes#qpage_1-apage_1-qsort_views-asort_votes`

If we look at the javascript in question:

```
function loadAnswers(b, a) {
    loadUrl("/api/useranswers.html?pagesize=" + answersPageSize + "&userId=" + userId, "#answers-table", b, a)
}
```

we see that url for the ajax call is hard coded and thus does not *need* to be on the `<a>` tag.  This seems to imply this can be easily fixed, but as I said there is no guarantee that page is constructed in such a way it can be fixed.

While SO cannot guarantee user experience in the case of failure, I think they can still improve the user experience with this change, providing some level of disaster recovery.

Comment: I get fragment of page using "Open in New Tab"...

Comment: @Jakub does it look like [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/api/userquestions.html?userid=137041&page=1&pagesize=10&sort=recent)?

Comment: Yes (though posting link would not ensure that I know how it looks like in your web browser, or how it looked like at the time of posting).

Comment: @Jakub the link I presented gives me a fragment of a page as well.  This is expected value.  Because it is accessing the API directly, you'll notice none of the DOM nodes have CSS in them.  This causes the fragment look.  What I expect to see is [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137041/tzenes#qpage_1-apage_1-qsort_views-asort_votes) instead.  The issue here is that opening with `Open in New Tab` produces a fragment instead of the correct page.

Answer (score 6):

Starting with the next build, these links will work when opening in a new tab, etc.  The user page should function the same as before, but be quite a bit cleaner behind the scenes, enjoy.

Answer (score 4):

I'm bumping this because it's still unresolved and I just had to close [my own post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103308/pagination-links-in-profiles-point-to-html-snippets-for-ajax-not-actual-pages) as a dupe of this.

Misusing `href` in this way is ugly and (according to this question) not even necessary for the current code. Opening several pages in new tabs is a habit common to many users, and this breaks that rather ungracefully.