# Links choosing sort order in 'favorites' tab of one's own user page have &amp; in URL and don't work for "open in new tab"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-interface, hyperlinks, profile-page

On one's own User Page (tested on StackOverflow site), on <kbd>favorites</kbd> tab: https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058?tab=favorites, the links which should select sort order, i.e. "added", "recent", "views", "newest", "votes" links are double HTML encoded, containing `&amp;` in place of `&` (or even better `;`).

For example link is:

- `https://stackoverflow.com/api/userfavorites.html?page=1&amp;pagesize=15&amp;userid=46058&amp;sort=recent`

and should be

- `https://stackoverflow.com/api/userfavorites.html?page=1&pagesize=15&userid=46058&sort=recent`

This does not matter if you just click on link, as SO would then use Ajax to update page, landing on

- `https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058?tab=favorites#fpage_1-fsort_recent`

But it does matter when I use 'Ctrl-Click' or 'Open in new tab' to open in new tab (landing on "Page Not Found").  You can also see this incorrect URL on mouseover (on hover) in the status bar area.

When I edit link to the second version it works correctly.

---

The <kbd>stats</kbd> tab doesn't have this bug.

Comment: Stats tab may not double-encode, but it still [has issues when doing Open in New Tab](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70335/links-on-user-page-are-assembled-to-the-wrong-destination).

Answer (score -1):

HTML 4.01 strict requires ampersand to be encoded.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Fixing_common_validation_problems#Ampersands

> Because the ampersand character (&) is reserved for marking character entities, authors should never use raw ampersands in their HTML source-- and that includes ampersands inside URLs! Thus, any URL that needs an ampersand should be written like this:
>
> `http://www.site.web/path/doc.html?var1=val1&amp;var2=val2&amp;var3=val3`

Comment: But they're *double* encoded as `&amp;amp;` on that page, which is the issue.

Comment: @tim ah, that would be bad then. Sorry, I wasn't getting that part..