# Pagination links in profiles point to HTML snippets for Ajax, not actual pages

Tags: bug, profile-page, pagination

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Links on user page are assembled to the wrong destination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70335/links-on-user-page-are-assembled-to-the-wrong-destination)

I middle-clicked on a pagination link in my profile...

[image]

...and when I clicked on the new tab, I was startled to see nothing but [the unformatted data from the next page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/stats/answers?page=2&userid=1114&sort=recent):

[image]

It looks like the `href`s on the pagination links are the URLs used to retrieve the content with AJAX, not an actual URL that users are intended to use.

I can see how this makes the code a little simpler but it doesn't make semantic sense and screws up things like this which expect `href`'s value to be meaningful.

Comment: Hm, I'm surprised this wasn't fixed when the profile got updates, but it seems not.

Comment: I find great novelty being voting to close without enough rep, even if it's my own question.